# getting values from Iframe to Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, iframe

I have an requirement like we will show an Iframe in product details page. Then user will do some configuration and he clicks on Addtocart in the Iframe, I need to add the product to the our cart(spring MVC).

How this can be achievable? Even Though if they send a rest call to our Spring MVC machine we cannot able to add this item to the session cart and how we can refresh the storefront page to show the cart update?

The Iframe is an cross domain Iframe.

Comment: do you control both domains and can insert code in iframe? What is a `PDP`?

Comment: yes..we can insert code in  iframe. Sorry PDP stands for product details page.

Comment: can use postMessage API to communicate between windows. Then add some ajax in main window

Comment: Thanks charlietfl.I will go through postMessage API